# MSYS2 installer

Tags: installation, build, msys2, openblas

After installing MSYS2 installer 32bit for Windows 10, I followed the instructions given on http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/windows.html#building-openblas to build OpenBLAS. After an apparent successful installation, I open a MSYS2 MinGW terminal and type the following: pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-i686-cmake git. I got the error message:

MSYS ~
$ pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-i686-cmake git
error: mingw32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57? [Y/n] y
error: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" could not be looked up remotely
error: mingw64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57? [Y/n]
????????????????????????????????????????????????

This error occurs throughout using other command:
pacman -Syu.

The version of MSYS2 installed is:

## Mintty 3.1.4 (i686 -pc-msys)
Created by Andy Koppe/Thomas Wolff

Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated for assistance to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have been to this page about creating your own GPG key: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Creating_GPG_Keys#Creating_GPG_Keys_Using_the_Command_Line.  I entered the command "gpg2 --full-gen-key", in MSYS2 terminal. The command is not recognized.

Comment: Thank you for your email reply. Yes. I'm using Windows 10 32 bit. I suppose I can upgrade the Windows 10 32 bit to 64 bit by a new installation. But, I need to install OpenBLAS in order to install scipy. I need to use MSYS to install OpenBLAS. Any helpful suggestion is welcome and appreciated.